# Most efficient javascript algorithm to calc total if amount were to double each day

Tags: javascript

Give N days, with money amount doubling each day, is this the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Day one: you are given $.5.
Day two: you are given twice the amount as day one $1, now you have $1.5
Day three: you are given twice the amount as day two $2 and now you have $3.5
And so on.

```
function calcit3()
{
  var cur_total = .5;
  var prev_total = 0;
  var days = 20;

  for ( z = 1; z < days; z++ )
  {
    cur_total = cur_total * 2;
    prev_total = cur_total;
  } 

  return (cur_total + prev_total);
}
```

This is just purely acedemic.  Not really trying to shave cycles or anything.

Thanks.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Is this homework? Not that there's anything wrong with it, but you should tag it as such if it is.

Comment: Na, not homework.  Just a watercooler question and everyone had a different answer.

Comment: Heh, homework spotters are always on vigil :) Obviously it is not, because its is well known problem from school algebra course http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: Your estimation of the result is incorrect. I suspect you're basing it on the code you've posted, which is wrong - try out your code with `days = 3` to see an example.

Comment: Check your math.  If i start with $.50, and i'm given $1 on day 1, $2 on day 2, $4 on day 3, etc...that is, if every day i'm adding twice as much...there's no other $.50 to make this a whole number.  Something's screwy about your numbers.

Comment: You are given $.50 on day one, then $1 on day two, $2 on day three and so on.

Comment: So you'll have $3.50 in total on day three. Your code says $3. So your code is wrong.

Comment: you're right.  i screwed up on the sheet.  just posted a fix.

Answer (score 9):

The code you've provided doesn't do what the description says it should.

If the initial amount is *a* then the amount you get on the *i* th day is `a * 2 ^ i`, and the sum after *n* days is the sum of that from 0 to *n*.

[Simplifying](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum), we get:

```
a * (2 ^ (n+1) - 1)
```

No looping necessary.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand the problem correctly, it's just a simple [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) starting with 0.5 and doubling in value each day. The total is nothing but the sum to `n` terms of this series, which is:

```
a * (r^n - 1)
-------------
   r - 1
```

Here `a = 0.5, r = 2`; substituting yields the formula:

```
0.5 * (2^n - 1)
```

Or equivalently in JavaScript:

```
return 0.5 * (Math.pow(2, days) - 1);
```

Comment: This isn't the correct answer.  This results in 524,287.5.  I believe it should result in 393,216.

Comment: Given the rules you've put forth, the math is right.  How would you get 393216.0 if every day you're adding some double of .5 (ie: every day you'd be adding some whole number to the total)?

Comment: Any idea how the Math.pow function works behind the scenes?  Is it actually looping as well?

Comment: `2^n` can be efficiently implemented as `1 << n` - I'm not sure which (if any) Javascript engines actually do this, though.

Comment: Nice.  Looks like that works.   return (.5 * 2) << (days - 1);

Comment: That's not quite it - if you run the numbers on that equation, you'll find you're always 50c off. A correct answer is `(1 << (days - 1)) - 0.5`

Comment: @Anon.: `1 << n` would only work for small values of `n` (only up to 31 on a 32-bit platform).

Comment: @user531427: There may be platform-specific instructions that a good JS engine can use to compute `Math.pow` efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
return (Math.pow(2.0, days + 1) - 1) * initial_amount;
```

No iteration necessary.  Given an initial_amount of .5, after 1 day, you'll have (2^2-1) * .5 == 1.5, after 2 days you'll have (2^3-1)*.5 == 3.5, etc.

Note, this assumes initial_amount on day 0, not 1.  If you're intent on having day 1 be the start, just remove the `+ 1` from the expression.

Also note, if you're talking about money, the formula is kinda odd.  Money would usually double daily, *including* the initial amount.  So on day 1, you'd have $1, on day 2 $2, day 3 $4, etc.

Comment: It isn't compounding interesting on money.  It is just a rule saying "hey, we'll give you twice the amount of money as the previous day"  At the end of the period, how much will you have.

Comment: Then you end up with ((2^end) + (2^end-1) + ... + (2^1) + (2^0)) * initial_amount.  That series is equal to ((2^(end+1)) - 1) * initial_amount.

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct?

```
return parseInt(Array(days).join('1'), 2) + 0.5
```

Comment: An odd approach, but just might work for a starting amount of 0.5.  Though you can easily calculate the number without resorting to creating a throwaway array, joining it, and parsing the resulting string as an int...